# Display form input ok wpforms

Tags: php, html, css, wpforms

I have a form that customers fill out and I'd like to know how to personalise the complete message with the customers name that they have input on the form.

Comment: Just `$_POST` data sent after form submission. Add your best attempt to get better help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant code any answer will just be a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it looks like this:

```
$client_name = $_POST["name"];
echo "Hello ".$client_name.", it's nice to meet you!"
```